# Azure Data Factory processed row count

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

We have ForEach iteration and within that we have Execute Pipeline activity. This activity call child pipeline which has copy activity. 
[image]

We have ID associated with every iteration and unique SELECT query to copy data. But we also want to update processed row count after each successful Execute Pipeline activity. Stored Proc activity (or any other way) should get processed row count and update into database. This is very easy in SSIS but can't figure out way to do this in Azure Data Factory.

I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51553141/azure-data-factory-check-rowcount-of-copied-records) SO post but this doesn't fit into our requirement. We don't want to change anything in child pipeline.

Comment: Could you deploy your SSIS process to Azure Data Factory 2?  Or use the Output command from a Merge statement to identify the number of rows affected?

Comment: We don't want to use SSIS package. Also we are not using Merge statement. We are using copy activity of ADF v2

Answer (score 0):

Currently, execute pipeline activity only output the pipeline run id and pipeline name of the child pipeline.

The easiest way would be to move the stored procedure activity into your child pipeline. If you don't want to change the child pipeline, maybe you could write [custom activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity) to get the pipeline run details based on the pipeline run id.